# in azure mobile app quick start don't display result

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I just want to create a windows 10 mobile app but in mobile app when i select quick start it doesn't display result and this error is shown.

Could not install MobileAppsManagement Site Extension.
SettingListPart
MICROSOFT_AZURE_MOBILESERVICES

This error is viewed after clicking on quick start

[image: Click to view Error screen shot: How to Get rid of this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is generally indicative of a browser issue and rarely of a permissions issue on the azure subscription that you are logging into.  Force reload the page or clear the cache and try again.