# Could not install MobileAppsManagement Site Extension

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I'm having a problem with Microsoft Azure. More specifically, I'm not able to get a mobile app up and running after creation and deployment. When I enter "Quick Start" in mobile apps settings, I get an error saying "`Could not install MobileAppsManagement Site Extension`" followed by "SettinListPart" and "MICROSOFT_AZURE_MOBILESERVICES". Thus I'm not able to initialize my backend.

I have a DreamSpark subscription (Student) active. I have had no problems with this earlier, and it occurred now that I moved over from free trial to DreamSpark subscription. (Free trial is disabled/inactive)

This seems to be the same or similar problem, however, I find no similar solution.
[in azure mobile app quick start don't display result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38105257/in-azure-mobile-app-quick-start-dont-display-result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your site is an F1 Free in the App Service Plan (which is a difference from the trial service), there should be no problems.  Steps for troubleshooting:

1. Go to your site, All Settings, Scale Down and ensure the F1 Free is chosen
2. You might have a cached permissions issue - do a hard refresh of your browser / clear the cache.